# Mensagem incorreta ao votar contra sua própria publicação

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Ao votar contra ou a favor de minha própria resposta recebo essa mensagem no SOEN:

> You can't vote for your own post

Aqui a mensagem é a seguinte:

> Você não pode votar **a favor** de sua própria publicação

Que não faz sentido caso eu tenha clicado em votar contra.

Comment: psss... Passa a tua sugestão para uma resposta, assim os utilizadores podem votar a favor ou contra. Mais tarde tens também a oportunidade de marcar a mesma como "Correta" e fechar este tópico quando existir um consenso sobre este assunto.

Answer (score 2):

Sugestão:

> Você não pode votar em sua própria publicação

Ou ainda:

> Não pode votar em uma publicação sua

Comment: Corrigido para "Você não pode votar no seu post"

Comment: @Gabe *acho* que PT_pt não receberia bem "post". Bom ver com alguém para confirmar/refutar.

Comment: Post é usado em PT_pt mas só para quem é programador ou da área da informática. Sendo que o SOpt é para esses mesmo, acho que não há qualquer problema.

Answer (score 1):

Eu optaria por uma abordagem mais genérica de forma a clarificar numa só leitura da mesma que a regra não é só para a publicação atual, mas sim para tudo: Perguntas, Respostas, Comentários.

> Não pode votar em nenhuma publicação realizada por si.

<sup>**Nota:**

Em Portugal seria escrito assim, mas se alguém fluente em Brasileiro tiver uma adaptação, deixe um comentário ou sugira uma edição da resposta.</sup>

Comment: "por si" é algo pouco visto no brasil. "publicação sua" substitui bem em portugal?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Não, :D Vou editar com outra sugestão, mas vi que já adicionaste essa ideia na tua resposta, assim fica também contemplada!

Comment: Zuul e Jorge B. defendendo (ahahahahah) o Português de Portugal. ;)